# How to set CRS on OpenStreetMap? V. 3.8

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap

I am completely new to QGIS and have a basic wuestion,
I am trying to create a map with OpenStreetMap and set it to a specific coordinate system. The problem is that when I set the CRS the map disappears. I literally have no idea what i'm doing.

First I try to set the CRS:
[image]

Then:
[image]

Then:
[image]

Then:
[image]

Then:
[image]

And nothing happens....please help.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't change the CRS of the Open Street Map layer.**

Return the CRS of the layer to the original CRS that it came with (which was probably EPSG:3857). If you don't remember for sure, remove the layer and re-add it the same way you added it the first time.

**Change the CRS of the Project.**

Click on the project CRS in the bottom-right corner of the window. This will open the CRS selector window. Choose your desired and click OK. QGIS will re-project everything in your map to the project CRS "on the fly."

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, so my end goal is to set the coordinates to "ETRS 1989 UTM Zone 32N 8stellen". I've tried your method of resetting the map and then clicking on the right hand lower corner and each option for Zone 32N brings up another blank screen. I'm an idiot on a foreign island, seriously.

Comment: I agree with the process that @csk describes (although at 3.8 the project CRS button is in the lower right window corner, not lower left).  Rachel, csk's procedure works fine for me with the closest CRS I can find to your needs, which is ETRS89 / ETRS-TM32.  View it at: https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3044/  However, my testing shows that there are still some CRS that result in a blank screen. for example changing the project CRS from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3338 fails to draw.  Weird, I dunno what's going on...